# Is there a way to use Spring Cloud {cipher} in Spring Boot application config?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a Spring Boot app that is using Spring Cloud Config but I would like to encrypt the Spring Cloud Config password in the Spring Boot apps bootstrap.yml file. Is there a way to do this? Below is an example.

Spring Boot app bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://locahost:8888
      username: user
      password: '{cipher}encryptedpassword'
```

Answer (score 20):

A couple things I've discovered related to this.

If you use bootstrap.yml (or application.yml), the format for the cipher text must enclosed within single quotes:

```
security.user.password: '{cipher}56e611ce4a99ffd99908d2c9aa1461d831722812e4370a5b6900b7ea680ae914'
```

If you use bootstrap.properties (or application.properties), the format for the cipher text must NOT be enclosed:

```
security.user.password= {cipher}56e611ce4a99ffd99908d2c9aa1461d831722812e4370a5b6900b7ea680ae914
```

The [reference docs][1] show the yml without the quotes, which I never got to work.  SnakeYaml always reported an error:

```
"expected <block end>, but found Scalar"
```

Comment: .properties files uses =, not ":"

Answer (score 11):

There is support for encrypted properties in the config client (as described in the [user guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_encryption_and_decryption_2)). Obviously if you do it that way you have to provide a key to decrypt the properties at runtime, so actually I don't always see the benefit (I suppose the config file is a bit like a keystore with a special format, so you only have one secret to protect instead of many). Example (application.yml):

```
integration:
  stores:
    test: '{cipher}316f8cdbb776c23e679bf209014788a6eab7522f48f97114328c2c9388e6b3c1'
```

and the key (in bootstrap.yml):

```
encrypt:
  key: ${ENCRYPT_KEY:} # deadbeef
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am not sure what I did wrong yesterday but I couldn't get it work. I had ENCRYPT_KEY set as an OS environment variable. I tried it again today and it is working.

Comment: For anybody with the same problem, Intellij (and probably other IDEs) load environment variables during startup... So to load new/changed environment variables, Intellij needs to be closed and restarted.

Comment: Could you please provide particular steps how to encrypt the password ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Spring CLI to encrypt the secrets `spring encrypt password --key 'SECRET_KEY'`

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/