# Spring boot cloud config encrypt keystore password

Tags: java, spring, encryption, keystore, keystore-access

The issue is for sure known. But i cannot find any solution. I'm using spring boot cloud config server to serve all properties values (encrypted) by {cipher} expression. It uses keystore located in the same system. But password to the keystore is in plain text. The question is there a possibility to some how encrypt the keystore password?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Encrypting the keystore password would require configuring a key for decryption which itself would have to be stored unencrypted, so there's no use in that.

I think the best way would be setting the keystore password as an environment variable (as described in [this post](https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/03/04/encrypting-and-decrypting-configuration-property-values-in-spring-cloud/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421252/is-there-a-way-to-use-spring-cloud-cipher-in-spring-boot-application-config) SO question).

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @Quagaar that the best way is to actually store it in an environment variable and have the `application.properties` read from there. Something like `server.ssl.key-store-password=${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}`
and set the environment variable in the run configurations for IDE or Export command on your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Its like creating a key for another key using a passphrase, multiple times you do that still will end having some passphrase in repository (like bitbucket).

Better to encrypt all passwords using config server encrypt.key: "{$somepassphrase}" and store this passphrase(master key) as env variable and pass it using Jenkins while generating a pipeline.