# Any way to use jasypt aes encryption and decryption for spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes, jasypt

I tried to encrypt and keep the db password in application.properties for my springboot application. When i use the des encryption, the application is able to decrypt the password and create the datasource object by itself.

When i tried aes, am getting ClassNotFoundException for PlaceholdersResolver

On further googling, i came to know that the issue is with version compatibility. So i started using lower version of jasypt. Then am able to use des, bt aes decryption fails due to different issues for different versions. So is there any particular version for aes using jasypt which is compactable for spring boot?

Comment: Check this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202568/how-to-encrypt-server-ssl-key-store-password-value-and-use-it-in-springboot

Comment: @NagarajuChitimilla thanks for the quick response.. i have tried the same. But in order to do that i need version 2.1.2 of jasypt. When i upgrade to that version am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PlaceholdersResolver" error.