# How to encrypt value for {cipher} in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud-config

I know how to use [Jasypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt)

But I've learned that there are alternative in spring stack using cipher:

```
security.user.password: '{cipher}56e611ce4a99ffd99908d2c9aa1461d831722812e4370a5b6900b7ea680ae914'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434892/2674303

But I have no idea:

1. How can I encrypt my password "superSecretPassword" ? (in case of Jasypt I used this service: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/jasypt-online-encryption-decryption)
2. Which algorithm will be used under the hood ? Could it be changed ?
3. What dependencies are required ? P.S. I don't use spring cloud in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the [Spring Boot CLI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html) and add the [Spring Cloud CLI](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/reference/html). You then can run the `spring encrypt` and `spring decrypt`. These pages will instruct you on how to install and how to run these commands.

I don't believe you can change the encryption algorithm and I haven't found what algorithm is used.

Comment: You also need to include spring-cloud-starter-config in your project.

Comment: Let me some time to try please